# How to center a vertical nav bar?

Tags: nav

A bit of background to start. I just finished the fundamentals of html/css on teamtreehouse.com. Going out and practicing a bit. My first project is a basic portfolio site. I would love a vertical nav bar. Just, centered. I can not seem to figure it out. This is what I have so far. 
(https://codepen.io/greenthingsjump/pen/vajbKZ)

### (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="Chrome">
  <title>Joshua Wolfe</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css" />
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-header">
    <p>
      <h1>Joshua Wolfe</h1>
    </p>

    <nav class="nav-bar" class='text-centered'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="C:\Users\Joshua Wolfe\Documents\Web Sites\joshuamwolfe\Index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="C:\Users\Joshua Wolfe\Documents\Web Sites\joshuamwolfe\About.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="C:\Users\Joshua Wolfe\Documents\Web Sites\joshuamwolfe\Skills.html">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="C:\Users\Joshua Wolfe\Documents\Web Sites\joshuamwolfe\Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="C:\Users\Joshua Wolfe\Documents\Web Sites\joshuamwolfe\Contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="C:\Users\Joshua Wolfe\Documents\Web Sites\joshuamwolfe\Blog.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>

  </main>
</body>
```

(CSS)

```
/* Nav-Bar */    
.nav-bar {
    background: #181818;
    width: 85px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
    text-align: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;


}

.nav-bar a {
    color: white; /* Text color */                                                 
    display: block; /* Make the links appear below each other */
    padding: 10px; 
    text-decoration: none;    
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}

.text-centered {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
}
   /* Body */

body {
       background-color: darkolivegreen;
     }

.main-header {
       /* background: url("img/benjamin-davies-265095-unsplash.jpg") no-repeat top center; */
       text-align: center;
       padding: 25px 25px;
       margin: 5px 5px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: way fancier then i need but example nav bar im shooting for.

https://jacekjeznach.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to center the text within the nav bar, but keep the whole thing left-oriented? It looks like there's some extra padding throwing things off.

Try:

```
ul {
padding: 0px;
}
```

**Edit:** The nav items aren't centering vertically in their space because the syntax applying two classes to the `<nav>` is incorrect. Try changing line 19 of your HTML to `<nav class="nav-bar text-centered">` and you should see the text-centered CSS class apply. Hope that helps!

Comment: I wanted the links in the center of the black bar. Also, you were right about the padding Karen.

But, yes, centered and left oriented.

Comment: @JoshuaWolfe I think I understand--text should be centered horizontally and vertically. I edited my answer to show why your CSS justify content property wasn't having any effect. :)

Comment: It worked!! <3. The con however is that the black bar is much smaller now... I'll work on that. Anywho thanks. :)